# Use a USB HDD connected to a Wi Fi router as a backup for both Windows Desktop and MacBook pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, wireless-networking, backup

i've a macbook pro with Retina ( running latest osX, 10.9 i guess ) and a desktop with Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. Can i buy a router with a usb port [like this one](http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B005T3TIBK/ref=s9_simh_gw_p147_d0_i5?pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0Q9AG2FVACBPSTWGB32C&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=451014987&pf_rd_i=426865031), connect a USB HDD to it and use it as a backup solution for both my MAcBook and Windows desktop?

EDIT - the question is not related to the single product, i'd like to know what do i need to look at in general to use a USB HDD connected to a router as a backup option for both OsX and Windows at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Asus' [specifications](http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN66U/specifications/) says it supports being used as a Samba (aka SMB) file server.

Windows 7 (Professional or Ultimate) Backup and Restore will accept this as backup location.  OS X Time Machine is usually limited to Apple-branded "Time Capsule" devices, but [can be made to use SMB locations](http://lifehacker.com/5685547/how-to-set-up-time-machine-to-back-up-to-a-networked-windows-or-linux-machine) (see step two).

Comment: so there is the need for some sort of specification?I mean the question is more generic and not related to that router only, i'll modify it.

Comment: Maybe just add in that Windows 7 Backup requires the Professional version or higher. It would help make this answer useful to other Windows 7 Home Basic or Home Premium, or even Home Starter users. As well, can you list the steps to make the Time Machine read an SMB share? I've done it, so I know it works, but if that link ever goes down, this answer becomes kinda useless. Thanks